# Problems with Yocto USB power management

Tags: linux, usb, yocto, suspend, sysfs

Started to work with Yocto and is trying to get a modem to sleep using USB suspend. According to the guides I've seen, you can do this in the sysfs with some power configs/commands.

I think I have figured out the path to my device (Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1e2d:005b) as /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1:1.3.

There is a power folder here, but it is empty. There should as I understand it be several files here, like wakeup, control, autosuspend_delay_ms, but there is none. Could I be missing some package for this?

Comment: You can set the modem vbus to OFF using /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb%/power/vbus. Do you need to enable wakeup from data ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you missed any of package in yocto. AFAIK it is function of the linux kernel to export some files under /sys/bus/devices. Maybe you didn't enable some features in kernel config file?

Comment: Might be this I suppose: "Extra PM attributes in sysfs for low-level debugging/testing". But if so, I guess it is not needed for it to work, just for testing. So I assume I should be able to get the modem to power save using udev rules without this option. So might be another problem.

Comment: Not quite the solution, that option added some files to the power folder, but only for debugging (async, runtime_active_kids, runtime_enabled, runtime_status, runtime_usage). Still no wakeup/control etc...